# How to retrieve deleted data from Iphone?

Tags: iphone, data-recovery

My data got deleted from iPhone. I tried to recover all images and videos using some third party softwares like dr.fone, stellar, etc but all these apps allow only preview of the data but can't actually save the data in my Windows PC unless we buy it.

So I wanted to take disk image of entire iPhone so that I can use Foremost app to recover some of my data. But I found no resources on how to take forensic image of my iPhone using dd imager and thereby retrieve required files.

If there is no way to recover files unless we buy a third party software, atleast help me in taking image of iPhone .

Thank you.

Comment: Third-Party software/applications are a hit or miss when it comes to recovering data of any sorts. You can try your luck at our sibling site! https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ See if any posts come up regarding this matter! All the best.